# Overlaying HTML text over three.js renderer

Tags: html, css, three.js

I am trying to overlay some HTML text over my three.js sketch, however changing the z-index does not change anything. I am aware that I could use innerHTML, however I am also going to need to use onclick attribute and that will cause me further issues which are not the main topic of this question.

For the example provided I am using a CSS3D renderer and I want to have the HTML content displayed to the side, however uppon changing padding values the whole body just drops lower as opposed to only the text.

Does anyone know whether such fix is possible?

EDIT:

```
 // WebGL renderer2
 renderer2= new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
renderer2.setClearColor(0xffffff, 1.0)
 renderer2.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
//renderer2.domElement.style.position = 'relative';
 renderer2.domElement.style.zIndex = '-1';
 document.body.appendChild(renderer2.domElement);
```

After some further investigation I decided to add another renderer so that CSS3D and WEBGL would be loaded at once on the same page, however upon changing both of those positions to relative, they end up being stacked one below the other and thus I have two canvases, ideally they would have to be stacked one upon the other and then have HTML text to the side.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <script src="http://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/renderers/CSS3DRenderer.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {

            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: white;

        }

        .text{

            z-index: 99;
            padding-top: 5%;

        }

        .large {
            font-size: xx-large;
        }
    </style>


</head>
<body>
    <div class="text">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>

<script>

    var string = '<div>' +
            '<h1>A test CSS3D example.</h1>' +
            '<span class="large">this is an input example</span>' +
            '<textarea> Try adding text here</textarea>' +
            '</div>';

    // global variables
    var renderer;
    var scene;
    var camera;

    function init() {


        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
        renderer = new THREE.CSS3DRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

        renderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
        renderer.domElement.style.zIndex= '1';

        camera.position.x = 500;
        camera.position.y = 500;
        camera.position.z = 500;
        camera.lookAt(scene.position);


        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
        var cssElement = createCSS3DObject(string);
        cssElement.position.set(100, 100, 100);
        scene.add(cssElement);

        render();
    }

    function createCSS3DObject(s) {

        var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
        wrapper.innerHTML = s;
        var div = wrapper.firstChild;


        div.style.width = '370px';
        div.style.height = '300px';
        div.style.transform = 'rotate(70deg)';
        div.style.opacity = 0.7;
        div.style.background = new THREE.Color(Math.random() * 0xffffff).getStyle();


        var object = new THREE.CSS3DObject(div);
        return object;
    }

    function render() {

        renderer.render(scene, camera);
         requestAnimationFrame(render);
    }

    window.onload = init;

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your three.js scene looks like it is in absolute positioning. This puts it in front of everything.

Comment: Thanks, changed the scene relative and text to absolute. Great work, a bit embarrassing that I overlooked something as simple as this.

Comment: However it does not seem to end there, as when I try adding another renderer to the scene it just messes things up again

Comment: Is this a html/css question that has little to nothing to do with three?

Answer (score 0):

Your class `text` has a z-index, however, you need to position it `absolute` or `relative` for the z-index to apply. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

If you provide a jsfiddle or a codepen, I'd be happy to give a you a more concrete answer.